# How does a Community & Site get linked to a guest profile?

Tags: deployment, profile, ant

I want to deploy a guest user profile to production without deploying the site it is related to. I then need to link this profile to the site in production. Is this possible? Advisable? Inconceivable?

Comment: I don't think the Profile exists outside of the Site context. You can create users with it in tests though...

Comment: Until you deploy the site to production (you don't have to make it live), the profile is irrelevant and will have no context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this some time ago but it is worth updating with the answer. It is linked by solely the profile name. For example, if I have a community with a guest profile I have configured and I make a new community, I can retrieve the profile from the first one and rename it to deploy to the second.